# The import android cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I've had 2 errors yesterday in the evening. I opened the project this morning and suddenly there were 22 errors. You can see my code below. I got this code sample from

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html

The errors are as follows:
1* The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
required .class files
1* The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
required .class files
2* import java.util cannot be resolved
6* The import android cannot be resolved
2* Activity cannot be resolved to a type
2* Override cannot be resolved to a type
2* ListView cannot be resolved to a type
1* The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity
4* string cannot be resolved to a type.
1* The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type

I hope this question isn't too dumb. I've tried a few things I found on stackoverflow but they didn't work.
Thanks for help and happy halloween.

```
       package ch.enerator.learning;
```

`import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initList();

    //We get the ListView component from the layout
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

     // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
     // Context
     // Data list
    // The row layout that is used during the row creation
    // The keys used to retrieve the data
    // The View id used to show the data. The key number and the view id must                     match

    List<? extends Map<String, ?>> planetsList = null;
    ListAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList,                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new
String[] {"planet"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
}

private void initList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}`

}

Comment: But what are errors ?

Comment: please paste the error log

Comment: ok sorry that was dumb. I've edited them in. Is it possible, that some sort of file is broken? As I said, these errors just apeared out of basicly nothing.

Comment: remvoe the duplicate `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Raghunandan that fixed one error. Unfordgenatley the rest is still there :/ any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that following this guide
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-comprehensive-troubleshooting-guide-for-androids-r-cannot-be-resolved-error/ solves the error. I'm not sure dough if "R cannot be found" is the exact cause of error.

Comment: Looks like you're answering your own question. Please use the same account in that case, to prevent getting flagged for reputation gaming. (Accepting a self-answer doesn't give you the +2/+15 rep normally given.)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed by right clicking on the project folder and selecting PROPERTIES
then i went to ANDROID and selected the right project built target
this seloved the issue